# Micro Cloud Foundry VM missing eth0

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to get Micro Cloud Foundry working under Windows 7 64 bit with VMware workstation 7.1.4.  For some reason, the VM starts with no eth0 only lo, therefore I never get a network connection.  Ideas?

Comment: I deleted the VM and started from scratch and the Ethernet adapter eth0 showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any other VMs running at the same time that may be using the same virtual adapter? Have you also checked the network settings on the VM to make sure a physical interface is selected on which to bridge the virtual adapter with.

Comment: No other VM running.  Will look at network setting on VMware adapter used for NAT.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to deleting VM and starting from scratch again, and loose all your work, you could also rename the folder that contains the VM image. When relaunching VM from renamed folder, VMWare will ask whether you "copied" or "moved" this VM. Select the "I moved" option and then VMware will recreate the ethernet adapter configuration for you and you are good to go from then on